# Does Stokes theorem have anything to do with adjoint functors?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors, derham-cohomology

I notice some similarity between Stokes theorem in differential geometry and the definition of adjoint functors:
in both cases, there is a 2-placed function (the $\operatorname{hom}$ functor, or the integral as a function of a submanifold and a form), a function that may apply to the left argument (the left adjoint or the boundary), and a function "in the other direction" that may equivalently apply to the right argument (right adjoint, or differential).

Is there a known connection between the two subjects?

---

Edit: I found this discussion at stack exchange:
[Is Stokes' Theorem natural in the sense of category theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225723/is-stokes-theorem-natural-in-the-sense-of-category-theory).

While not referring to adjoint functors specifically, there are ideas there that feel like a good connection to category theory (specifically, extranaturality and coends). The most helpful answer is close to what described here:
[Everything is Stokes'; everything is coend](https://thosgood.com/blog/2019/09/04/stokes-coend.html).

I would like to read more work in similar directions. And if there is also a categorical reason for *why* Stokes theorem holds — that would be best.

Comment: Yes, but a closer analogy would be with a [**coend**](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/end), which is one of many things that are equivalent to adjoints. I will leave it to some categorist who is more familiar with differential geometry than me to explain this fully.

Comment: Thanks Paul! Your mention of coends was enough to find some promising things at Google

Comment: I don't know enough category theory to understand precisely what you're asking. I was wondering if you could formulate and probably answer your question for the 1D case, which is simply the fundamental theorem of calculus. I also wanted to observe that Stokes's theorem on a smoothly rectangularized manifold can be proved very easily using only the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225723/is-stokes-theorem-natural-in-the-sense-of-category-theory/) an old attempt to make Paul's comment precise. I believe Fosco Loregian was planning to develop this in more detail in print at some point. (Oh -- I see you've already linked to this!) In the end, though, Stokes' theorem encodes some real geometry, and I would be very suprised if there were a "mostly category-theoretic" _proof_ of Stokes' theorem...

Comment: Is the "most helpful" answer to which you refer [@tcamps's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1229249)?

Comment: Maybe the maximal categorical role one could reasonably expect would be a proof of Stokes which might decompose as “fundamental theorem of calculus + category theory”. Maybe with a restriction to framed manifolds or something.

Comment: The "maximal categorical role" is only limited by imagination. Uufortunately,  most mathematician just use category theory like wrapping paper.  If you're up for serious applications to understanding mathematical ideas, try **synthetic differential geometry**.  There is an excellent book of this title by Anders Kock.  Other researchers include Bill Lawvere, Eduardo Dubuc, Marta Bunge, Jonathon Funk.